# download file log from blob storage using node js

Tags: azure

I download a file from azure blob storage by blobService.getUrl(container, blobName, sasToken).
on Internet Explorer, I see source of URL download.
you can see the [image]

Could you help me how to rename from download ?

Comment: Are you looking to hide the download URL or change the name of the file on download?

Comment: @GauravMantri i want to hide the download URL or change https://candadevstorageaccount.blob..... to https://example.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to hide the account name, you could map a custom domain to your blob storage endpoint for example, map `mydomain.com` to `myaccount.blob.core.windows.net`.

You will find this link useful for mapping a custom domain to blob storage endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name.

Comment: No, i don't want to change blob storage domain, i only want to change title source download. Instead of showing blob domain, i'll show domain of web app

Comment: If that is the case, you will need to download the blob first on your web server and then stream it from there.